# How to get DB records which have different value of same column in same table

Tags: sql, sybase

Please take a look of below SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 3 acct_num from acct_package
where package_key IN 
(
  select package_key from acct_serv 
  where serv_id  = 'A1'
  and package_key IN (                                                    
                        select package_key from acct_serv 
                        where serv_id  = 'B1'
                        and package_key IN(
                                            select package_key from acct_serv 
                                            where serv_id  = 'C1' 
                                          )
                     )
)
```

In case, no other tables had relationship.

I can retrieve the data I need by the above SQL, but I guess maybe have other coding are more effective.

many thanks for helping!!!

Comment: Please add more details viz. some sample data and required output, to understand better your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach (please remember to use ORDER BY when you use TOP xx, otherwise result is not predictable) (I tried it on Oracle DB, without TOP of course):

```
SELECT TOP 3 ACCT_NUM 
FROM ACCT_PACKAGE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT PACKAGE_KEY, SUM(RC) AS SUM_TOT
            FROM (SELECT PACKAGE_KEY, SERV_ID, 1 AS RC
                  FROM ACCT_SERV
                  WHERE SERV_ID IN ('A1','B1','C1')
                  GROUP BY PACKAGE_KEY, SERV_ID      
                  ) B 
            GROUP BY PACKAGE_KEY
            ) C ON A.PACKAGE_KEY = C.PACKAGE_KEY
WHERE SUM_TOT >=3   
ORDER BY A.PACKAGE_KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 3 acct_num 
from acct_package ap
where exists (select 1 
              from acct_serv a1 
              where a1.package_key = ap.package_key and serv_id = 'A1')
and exists (select 1 
            from acct_serv a2 
            where a2.package_key = ap.package_key and serv_id = 'B1')
and exists (select 1 
            from acct_serv a3 
            where a3.package_key = ap.package_key and serv_id = 'C1')
```